# Reading from an "in" file and writing to an "out" file in C++ using the input output stream

Tags: c++11, filestream

I need to access data stored in a file with ".in" extension using C++ and write the output to a ".out" file.

How should I go about it?

Comment: This is just like reading and writing to files. Extensions carry no special information here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will be using Windows for this. The ".in" file (let's say input_file.in) can be opened and viewed using the notepad.

Using a C/C++ program, follow the following steps:

- Write your code (let's say code.c) using cin and cout with no additional change.
- Compile it.
- You will see a "code.exe" and "code.out" file generated in the program directory.
- Using the command line, go to this program directory and execute the command to ask the input stream to stream data in the ".in" file.

```
code <input_file.in
```

This will still print the "cout" streamed data to the terminal. To instead save the output to a .out file (let's say output_file.out), you also need to change the output stream to write to this file.

```
code <input_file.in >output_file.out
```